# Should I send a delayed thank-you two weeks after the interview?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I interviewed at a mid-size company (on-site) about 2 weeks ago and I totally forgot to send a follow-up thank-you email to my interviewer for showing me around the company and the great experience etc. etc.  (I mean it, I really did enjoy visiting the company and seeing the opportunities).

Should I still send a thank-you? Or should I just wait for the company to send me their decision and then thank them at that time for the interview opportunity (to at least save the bridge for the future, I guess?)

(This question is different from [this other question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/how-long-should-i-wait-before-sending-a-thank-you-email) since I'm already stuck in the situation of being too late, and now I'm debating whether it's still worth it to send the thank-you. The other question doesn't recommend a course of action if you're late in sending)

---

Update: I sent no follow-up and still got extended an offer a few weeks later. Worked out well!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long should I wait before sending a thank you email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/how-long-should-i-wait-before-sending-a-thank-you-email)

Comment: IMO, the ideal time to send a follow-up email is 3-4 business days after the interview, maybe a day less if you interviewed on Friday. The purpose of a follow-up email is to simply show that you're interested, and that you're assertive.. it shouldn't be to remind them of your existence. =P

Comment: @Charles yes, it would be odd to send a followup so late! Glad the OP got the offer though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've not sent one right away, there's little point.

The company will probably interpret this as you chasing them for a decision or trying to bump up your chances, and may not take kindly to it.

Just wait for their decision, like everyone else is.

Comment: well, that and that you are the type of person who doesn't understand when followup emails should be sent!

Answer (score 1):

Send the thank-you.

You have no idea what the hiring manager or HR at that company is thinking, or even IF they're thinking about you.  Don't interpret too much into their silence, as you don't know their timeline for hiring the position.  They may always take a month to decide who to hire, it may have to go through some informal committee that hasn't met yet, yadda, yadda... What do you have to lose? This [link](http://www.thankyoudiva.com/belated-and-late-thank-you-notes-cards-letters.html) has some really good arguments for always sending the thank-you, even if you're late.  Such as, "There's a 99% chance that the person who gave you the gift, invited you to the event or did you a kindness or favor is keenly aware that you haven't thanked them."  The site has sample wording as well.  You can't go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm 2 weeks late in sending a follow-up thank-you after my interview. Should I still bother?

Better late than never. But don't expect an answer back if the company didn't select you to move forward in the hiring process.

Comment: Why is late better than never? It might show your interest, but it also probably shows that you couldn't have been bothered to write the email 2 weeks earlier, and there's a decent chance that they already made their decision at that point.

Comment: This is not good advise.  Saying thanks this late in the game is more of an insult to the hiring folks than a benefit to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't. If you truly wish to say thank you then i'd do it on a personal level or pass by. If it's truly a company you see your future developing then by all means, don't be passive! be unique is from my experience the best way to go.