# What should be the title of "Thank you" email?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, job-search, email

How should I title my "thank you" e-mail after technical phone interview? Is just "thank you" itself enough?

Is there some accepted practice?

**EDIT**

The previous time I was actively looking for a job I still had CompuServe e-mail address, so I simply out of loop with Internet age practices.  Since I do not want to look like a dinosaur I'm googling, asking around, and posted this question here.

Comment: Do you mean a 'Thanks, but no thanks' email, or a follow-up moving the recruitment process forward?

Comment: A simple `Thank You for the Interview` as subject?

Comment: Hey PM-77, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As explained in our [help/on-topic], questions should focus on a specific problem that you are facing. Is there a specific reason a title of 'Thank You' is a problem for you? As-is, this just seems to be polling for opinion. If you could [edit] the question to make it fit the guidelines in our [help], you will get better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CMW - Follow-up after the first phone interview with the company.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/send-thank-you-email-after-phone-interview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stay way from using the word "thanks" in your subject line. A lot of email servers tend to plop emails with the subject line "Thanks" into people's spam folders or even worse, just block them. I would maybe prefix the subject line with "Interview dd/mm/yyyy - " just to distinguish it from the usual spam onslaught.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for weighing in. This bordered on possibly being better as a comment to Joe's answer, and I considered converting it. Instead, I edited out the reference to Joe's answer and added an explicit plea to avoid the word "thanks" based on your explanation. Feel free to put that in your own words if needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I title my "thank you" e-mail after technical phone
>   interview? Is just "thank you" itself enough?
>
> Is there some accepted practice?

When I send a follow-up email, the subject often says simply "Thank You" or even just "Thanks".

I know of no "accepted practice" here, but I don't think the Subject line for simple thank you emails is overly important, anyway. Since it's coming from you, and the recipient presumably remembers your interview, they are sure to read it anyway. Capturing the potential reader's attention is the point of the Subject, and that really doesn't apply here. The contents are where you want to spend most of your time and energy.

Express your thanks. Reflect on what you heard. Expand on any points you think will put you in a better light. Show why you fit so well for the position. Show enthusiasm. Ask the interviewer about the next steps and the timing if appropriate.

Make sure there are no typos or grammatical errors, and in particular make sure the name is correct.