# Letter of thanks for an office invite by a potential employer

Tags: interviewing, work-environment, ethics, relationships

I have been invited to spend a day at a workplace after almost 7 grueling rounds of interviews, with an invite as this being the last phase to wrap up their decision. I am looking to draft a thank you letter for showing me around the place and helping me understand their work ethics. But how do I also make sure that i reiterate my candidacy and skills in this mail along with an effective thanksgiving.

The other samples on this site have not been touching points of an office invite thanksgiving or anything similar.

Thanks!

Re edit:

Since the position I am applying for looks to have me in the Journalism sector, it would be great if I could have a sample mail that points my interest in being an effective editor along with a thank you note for all the efforts gone into interviewing.

Comment: Hi Learning_fly. The Workplace is not really the best site for "suggest how I do this" type questions. Unfortunately, your question is very subjective in it's nature, as there isn't one answer or one proper response, and thus this site isn't really the best place to get a solid answer that will benefit you and others here. Could you be slightly more specific with your question?

Comment: @panoptical Sure. I shall try my best to further elucidate my point. Please check the re edit.

Comment: The answers to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/should-a-thank-you-letter-be-sent-after-an-interview/19203#19203 also have examples of what to say in a followup letter.

Answer (score 4):

I would keep the letter/email purely on point as a thank you.

As you have been through several rounds of interview and been invited in for a visit, I would say there is no need to reiterate your candidacy. They obviously have liked what they have seen so far and consider you a very desirable candidate otherwise you would not have progressed this far.