# What's the best approach to following up after interviews?

Tags: interviewing, email, follow-up

I recently submitted a resume which went directly to the hiring manager. He asked me for an interview the next day and I agreed. At the end of the interview, I received his contact information and he asked me to attend a second interview with another manager the following day. This process has taken part over 3 days so far.

My question is do I only follow up with the first manager that I saw on the second day as the thought of sending two thank-you emails within 24 hours seems a bit like a spam. Or alternatively do I send a single follow up email that addresses them both?

Answer (score 3):

**No, you don't need to send one yet.**

You're right, that many emails in such a short period of time would be annoying, particularly since you already have another interview with them booked. Save any follow-up emails until after the interview period is done. If they are maintaining contact with you, then there isn't really a need for a follow-up. They are most useful after the interview period is over and they've told you that they will contact you once they've made their decision.

Also, if/when you do decide to send a follow-up note, keep in mind [what they are really about](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/19203/16983).