# I agreed to send my revised resume to a contact within about three days. Should I still send a 'thank you" email the day after the meeting?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, united-states

Essentially, we've already agreed to a follow up, where I send an updated resume to my contact based on what I learned in our conversation. We agreed that I'll send the revised resume within a few days.

A good rapport was established. Sending a simple "thank you" note the day after our meeting seems pointless. I can thank him again when I send the resume. But, I don't want to contradict best practices in business etiquette.

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful to see two, competing views. I thanked the person verbally, and we had good rapport. I think in this case, an immediate "thank you" email could be seen as a hollow strategy, rather than genuine gratitude (which I already expressed on the phone). "Ah, this guy read somewhere about sending a thank-you note, and so he did." I might err on the side of reiterating my gratitude when I send my updated resume.

Comment: An immediate thank you email would be rather goofy. Your question said `the day after our meeting` which would just be keeping your name in front of him the next day.  But no, I wouldn't thank him in person and then email him right after. :)

Answer (score 1):

You only really need to send one email. Just include your "Thank You" when you send the updated resume. If you are going to send a thank you, it doesn't have to be the day after your interview - as long as you're within a week you're fine. Even then, not everyone agrees that a Thank You on it's own is necessary: ([Should a thank you letter be sent after an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/should-a-thank-you-letter-be-sent-after-an-interview))

Answer (score 0):

Always send a thank you. It's not pointless, it's courteous. You're thanking the person for meeting with you.

The intangible is that you're also keeping your name in their mind.

A better question is why wouldn't you?  It's harmless and at worst the person would think "I didn't really need a thank you".

There are some positives and no negatives. Always send a thank you.  You never know when it could make the difference when everything else is equal.