# Is it OK to send a thank you email to only one interview panel member?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-search, recruitment

I had an interview this morning with a panel of 5. One of the members of the panel, I'll call Bob, is the would-be superior for the position, and gave me a tour after the interview. With this, I definitely want to send Bob a thank you email.

Would it be inappropriate to send **only Bob** a thank you email, and **not the rest of the panel?** I unfortunately do not remember the name of one of the 5 panel members.

It was Bob and one other employee that interviewed me first, and I sent a single thank you email to both of them. The HR recruiter did not participate in either of these interviews, and for this reason, I am not sending a thank you to this recruiter. Is this the right move?

Comment: I assume you don't have the email of the rest of the panel members, correct?

Comment: No I do, I'm only missing one.

Comment: How did you obtained those emails? And how come you don't know their names if you have their emails?

Comment: Their emails are listed on the company website. And it's only one panel member whose name I've forgotten. I remember everybody else's.

Answer (score 2):

> It was Bob and one other employee that interviewed me first, and I sent a single thank you email to both of them. The HR recruiter did not participate in either of these interviews, and for this reason, I am not sending a thank you to this recruiter. Is this the right move?

It's okay.

> One of the members of the panel, I'll call Bob, is the would-be superior for the position, and gave me a tour after the interview. With this, I definitely want to send Bob a thank you email.
>
> Would it be inappropriate to send only Bob a thank you email, and not the rest of the panel?

*Short answer:* Yes.

---

*Longer answer:*

Given that you state that you want to thank for the tour, I think you answered yourself. As the other members didn't give you a tour, it wouldn't make sense to thank them for such, thus thanking Bob only seems logical.

Different case would be if you wanted to thank for the second interview, case where it would make more sense to email all the ones involved. However, **I feel it would seem a bit out of place or odd to write** (and receive) **such email if you didn't have their contacts in the first place** (in fact, the other members may be startled).

Furthermore, you mention in a comment that:

> Their emails are listed on the company website. And it's only one panel member whose name I've forgotten. I remember everybody else's.

It is now clear that you had to manually <s>stalk</s> search for their contacts, so sending them an email would *surely* make them wonder how or who gave you their contact information. Considering all these things I say it would be out of place to email the members of the panel that you didn't had their contacts before.

---

Another point to have in mind is that **you already thank Bob and other person previously**. It seems to be [a common thing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/19196/73791) to send thank you letters, and the community seems to consider it Ok... however, sending multiple thank you letters, to basically as much people involved that you can (and sometimes more than once to some people) could be a bit *too much*, and worst case perceived as *flattery*.

I mention these things so you have them in mind when deciding if you send or not the thank you email(s). If you feel it could be perceived as flattery or out of place, I would avoid it. Perhaps what's best for you is to write to Bob only, thanking him for the tour.

Comment: My only concern is that Bob will think, "why is he only thanking me if he also thanked the other person last time?" But 5 people is different than 2 people, and I'm sure he'll recognize that. Thank you so much for your insights

Comment: @otonomi and how could Bob know you are only thanking him (unless he somehow had knowledge of the emails the other people get)? I think it is unlikely Bob will think that and, perhaps, you are over-thinking that a bit to be honest...

Comment: You're right, thank you...I hope I didn't go too far the first time by emailing Bob without actually getting his email address from him. But since I already did that once, I might as well follow suit.

Comment: @otonomi so you also ... "stalked" their email info? :o did he reply to your first thank-you email?

Comment: If obtaining Bob's email address through the website's staff directory is "stalking", then yes, I did. And no, he didn't respond to the first email. Is that important?

Comment: Just wanted to have a better view on the situation. Thanks (It's not "stalking" but also you didn't obtain it organically), I hold what suggested in my answer: consider thanking only Bob

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be inappropriate to send only Bob a thank you email, and not
>   the rest of the panel? I unfortunately do not remember the name of one
>   of the 5 panel members.

That is unfortunate. But it appears that sending it to just one is the best you can do, so it makes sense to go ahead and send your thanks to Bob.

Make sure you ask Bob to thank the others on the panel for you.