# After an all-day interview does one send a follow-up/thank you note to every interviewer?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

These answers suggest sending a thank-you note to an interviewer is a good idea:

(1) [Should a thank you letter be sent after an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/should-a-thank-you-letter-be-sent-after-an-interview)

(2) [Send “thank you” email after phone interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/send-thank-you-email-after-phone-interview)

I recently went through an 8 hour all-day interview of nine consecutive interviews all with senior folks.  I was interviewed due to an employee referral (who obviously did not take part in the actual interviews).

Would this scale up, and thus should I send nine separate thank-you notes, or should I just stay in contact with the employee who referred me?

Comment: Well, according to the links you gave us, it seems to have no real matter. YOU don't know who other candidates might be, hence you have no idea where you really stand. In other words, it can be rather obsolete in therms of your standpoint. Besides, if you did thank after each interview on-spot, and you felt the interview went great and everything was covered, what more is there to say? Nothing, so conclusion is: If you want, but don't expect it to matter.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure that you already thanked them face to face for their time. The only reason you are sending a thank you note is to remind interviewers that you interviewed with them and that you are looking for an update, without explicitly saying so.

If you want to send a thank you note, send it to the decision maker assuming that you identified that person. Failing that, send the thank you note to the person who notified you of the interview. In both cases, say that you are thanking everyone and if they are looking for anything else from you, to let you know.

Comment: I agree except that the intent (at least for me) isn't asking for an update but rather a way of saying, "I'm still interested and unlike a lot of technically-inclined people, I'm not devoid of social graces"  :)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Okay, rub it in :)